# Ignoring unused parameter with code sniffer

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

I'm running the codesniffer with the [EcgM2](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/EcgM2/ruleset.xml) standard on my custom extension and I'm getting the warning

> The method parameter `$context` is never used

for the `InstallSchema.php` file.
**How can I make this warning go away?**
My method looks like this (notice the `SuppressWarnings` at the top of it):

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    //my install script here that does not use the parameter $context
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to hide the dirt under the rug like this:

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) 
{
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
....
}
```

I'm not proud of it, but it works.

Comment: adding the ```// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd``` between the method signature and the opening curly brace will cause a phpcs warning - _phpcs: opening brace should be on the line after the declaration; found 1 blank line(s)_

Comment: right. it can be added after the opening bracket. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Update phpcs (squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) to latest (v3.2.3 at 2017-03-06) and use like:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
// phpcs:ignore Generic.CodeAnalysis.UnusedFunctionParameter
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    //my install script here that does not use the parameter $context
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the right way:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * phpcs:disable Generic.CodeAnalysis.UnusedFunctionParameter
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    //my install script here that does not use the parameter $context
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the suppress warning rule you will have to use is:

```
Generic.CodeAnalysis.UnusedFunctionParameter
```

So this should be the code to use in your PHP Docblock:

```
@SuppressWarnings(Generic.CodeAnalysis.UnusedFunctionParameter)
```

Comment: thanks for digging this up, but it has no effect

Comment: @Marius hmm that's annoying

Comment: still not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if someone has the same configuration, it works for me but with OP's SuppressWarnings ! No other answer worked.

So `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)` actually works with PHPMD.