# The method parameter $context is never used

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I am getting this error when I submit my extension for technical review at magento marketplace .

I know there are answers available for this , I have gone through following questions as well 
[question 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171079/warning-the-method-parameter-context-is-never-used) &&  [question 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123188/ignoring-unused-parameter-with-code-sniffer).

but the answer provided there is not resolving the warning .

Here is my code

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rahul
 * Date: 31/7/18
 * Time: 4:37 PM
 */

namespace Rahul\DiscountPlugin\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * @var EavSetup
     */
    private $eavSetup;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     * @param EavSetup $eavSetup
     * @param Config $config
     */

    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetup,
        Config $config
    ) {
        $this->eavSetup = $eavSetup;
        $this->eavConfig = $config;
    }
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('discountplugin')
        )->addColumn(
            'vatpluginid',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'VatPluginId'
        )->addColumn(
            'apikey',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'ApiKey'
        )->addColumn(
            'endpoint',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'EndPoint'
        )->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Create date'
        )->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Updated date'
        )->setComment(
            'discount plugin table'
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $eavTable1 = $setup->getTable('quote');
        $eavTable2 = $setup->getTable('sales_order');

        $columns = [
            'save_vat_discount' => [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Input option',
            ]
        ];

        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable1, $name, $definition);
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable2, $name, $definition);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

can please anyone guide me what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: you have not used that variable that's why it shows error

Comment: Thanks @kunj , I am already aware about that I have not used that variable , thats why I am asking how to suppress that warning .

Comment: Addthis code `$context->getVersion();` after `$installer->startSetup();`.

Comment: Put before  public function install()
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart     
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)     
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

OR

As you can see in Magento default CMS installer : `/vendor/magento/module-cms/Setup/InstallSchema.php`

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
```

OR we can do this :

```
public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $context->getVersion();
```

Comment: Thanks but it still gives the same warning .

Comment: @RahulMakwana, I have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks , I tried that as well but still getting same warning .

Comment: $context->getVersion(); from your comment helps but I want to suppress that warning .

Comment: @RahulMakwana, I just tried this `// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart` it is working for me

Comment: @RahulMakwana, you can test that by PHPCS. you can try this for that : https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-verify-magento-2-source-code-with-m2-coding-sniffer/

Comment: Thanks , I have used // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart but it still shows the warning . I am adding my extension for technical review on magento marketplace and getting this warnings .

Comment: I wanted to suppress this warning but was not able to achieve the same but yes using the $context variable fix , I don't really like this as I wanted to suppress the warning but for now I am using like you suggested .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code for your file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rahul
 * Date: 31/7/18
 * Time: 4:37 PM
 */

namespace Rahul\DiscountPlugin\Setup;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        if (!$installer->tableExists('discountplugin')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('discountplugin')
            )->addColumn(
                'vatpluginid',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'VatPluginId'
            )->addColumn(
                'apikey',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'ApiKey'
            )->addColumn(
                'endpoint',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'EndPoint'
            )->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                'Create date'
            )->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                'Updated date'
            )->setComment(
                'discount plugin table'
            );
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $eavTable1 = $installer->getTable('quote');
        $eavTable2 = $installer->getTable('sales_order');

        $columns = [
            'save_vat_discount' => [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Input option',
            ]
        ];

        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable1, $name, $definition);
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable2, $name, $definition);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I tried your code but it still shows the same warning .

Comment: Can you remove the below code which updates quote and sales order table and test again.

Comment: ok let me try that .

Comment: I tried removing that block of code as well  but still getting that warning .

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the doc block of the function:

```
/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 * phpcs:disable Generic.CodeAnalysis.UnusedFunctionParameter
 */
```

The first line is to suppress warning for PhpMd, the latter for Phpcs.